# How can I earn Diplomatic Victory Points?

Tags: civilization-6-gathering-storm

How many ways are there to earn Diplomatic Victory points in Gathering Storm, beyond simply winning the World Leader Elections in the Diplomatic Congress?

I know there are some wonders that give you points, and a couple of technologies, but I wanted to get a list of all of them in one place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ways to gain and lose Diplomatic Victory points are:

**Wonders:**
Building the *Mahabodhi Temple* awards 2 Diplomatic Victory points.
Building the *Potala Palace* awards 1 Diplomatic Victory point.
Building the *Statue of Liberty* awards 4 Diplomatic Victory points.

**Technologies:**
Researching *Seasteads*, a technology of the Future Era, awards 1 Diplomatic Victory point.

**Civics:**
Discovering *Global Warming Mitigation*, a civic of the Future Era, awards 1 Diplomatic Victory point.

**Competitions:**
Earning the highest score in an *Aid Request* (or *Military Aid Request*) competition awards 2 Diplomatic Victory points.
Winning the first place in a non-Emergency *Scored Competition* awards 1 Diplomatic Victory point.

**World Congress**
Voting for the winning Outcome/Target combo of a World Congress Resolution awards 1 Diplomatic Victory point.
Late in the game, World Leader elections will be held during regular sessions of the World Congress. Each player can spend Diplomatic Favor to vote for one player to either gain 2 Diplomatic Victory points or lose 2 Diplomatic Victory points.

Source: https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Victory_(Civ6)#Diplomacy

Comment: Weird, I just got "World congress has awarded you 1 victory point" notification out of nowhere (~5 turns after last congress meeting). There was no any scored compotition, nor wonder buillt. Interesting what could be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

You also get a Diplomatic Victory Point each time you vote on the winning side of any World Congress vote (that's where the AI gets all their points from).

I'm trying to find a better way to guess what the AI is voting for, but so far I've failed at that.

Also note that the points in the other answer or not accurate anymore: for example, the Statue of Liberty gives 4 Points.

Comment: Yeah, they re-worked the whole system in a recent patch. I should update that.

Answer (score -1):

Just reload the game after the world congress votes and vote however they just voted. You’ll control the vote in your favor and get 2 diplomatic victory points. Also whenever the game presents an option to vote for one person to get some benefit just vote 2 votes for yourself. The game is selfish and frugal. The other characters will always vote for themselves.